# Unable to visualize HSV Point Cloud in PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have captured a point cloud of type `PointXYZRGBA` as shown below-

[image: Point Cloud of type PointXYZRGBA]

I converted it to `PointXYZHSV` and tried to visualize it using 
[PCLVisualizer](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php). Surprisingly, PCLVisualizer is showing it as black and white as shown below-

[image: Point Cloud of type PointXYZHSV]

Below is the code snippet-

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZHSV PointHSV; 
typedef pcl::PointXYZRGBA PointRGBA; 
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointHSV> PointCloudHSV; 
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointRGBA> PointCloudRGBA; 

int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer"); 
    PointCloudRGBA::Ptr rgba_cloud (new PointCloudRGBA); 
    PointCloudHSV::Ptr hsv_cloud (new PointCloudHSV); 

    pcl::io::loadPCDFile("capture.pcd", *rgba_cloud); // read pcd
    pcl::PointCloudXYZRGBtoXYZHSV(*rgba_cloud, *hsv_cloud); // convert to hsv
    viewer.addPointCloud<PointHSV>(hsv_cloud, "hsv_cloud_name"); // show hsv

    viewer.spin(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The PCD file can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6btdq9pq8g274q/capture.pcd?dl=0). I am using PCL_VERSION: 1.8.1.99 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS.

I am worried since I am going to use PointXYZHSV for color-based segmentation of Point cloud later.

**How to visualize HSV Point cloud?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still digging into this problem, PCL Visualizer is not prepared to handle different color spaces other than RGB (and intensity types) for display purposes. Make use of [`pcl::PointXYZHSVtoXYZRGB`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/namespacepcl.html#a688582cb4b66085025fb42e354ac37fa) to handle the point cloud conversion

```
void pcl::PointXYZHSVtoXYZRGB (const PointXYZHSV& in, PointXYZRGB& out);
```